# OWL: scoped domain and range

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

What is the difference between *scoped domain* and *domain*? Also *scoped range* and *range*.   And how is it defined in Protege for a single property to have two different scoped domains or scoped ranges?

P.S. I mean using two different scoped domain means:
*R has range B if domain is A*
*R has range D if domain is C*

Comment: Do you mean by domain the assertion that the domain it owl:Thing and scoped domain any other class? (Similarly for datatype properties?)

Comment: Multiple domain declarations(same for ranges) mean that the domain is the intersection of all declarations.

Comment: @Ignazio I updated the question

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the domain of the object property `R` is `A` could be written  in this way:

```
R some owl:Thing SubClassOf A
```

The fact that the range of the object property `R` is `B` could be written in this way:

```
owl:Thing SubClassOf R only B
```

One can generalize these records slightly.

The domain of `R` scoped with / by `B` is `A`:

```
R some B SubClassOf A
```

The range of `R` scoped with / by `A` is `B`:

```
A SubClassOf R only B
```

In Protégé, one can type these axioms in these places (pressing the ⊕ button as many times as one wishes):

- *Active Ontology > General Class Axioms > General Class Axioms*, or
- *Entities > Classes >  [Class] > Description > General Class Axioms*.

Also, the OWLAx plugin can generate both scoped and non-scoped axioms.

---

In DL terms, scoped domain and range axioms are:

- **∃R.B ⊑ A** instead of **∃R.⊤ ⊑ A**,
- **A ⊑ ∀R.B** instead of **⊤ ⊑ ∀R.B**.

In SWRL terms:

- `B(?y) ^ R(?x,?y) -> A(?x)` instead of `R(?x,?y) -> A(?x)`,
- `A(?x) ^ R(?x,?y) -> B(?y)` instead of `R(?x,?y) -> B(?y)`.