# Best Practice for defining Properties?

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-web, rdfs

My problem with OWL/RDFS is, that by defining multiple ranges and domains, the reasoner will classify instances (which are defined as domain or range) as type of all defined classes for domain or range of that property.

What are possible solutions to overcome that problem?

- One way would be, using SHACL. But now, visualization-tools do not work anymore.

short example:

```
:ClassA a owl:Class .
:ClassB a owl:Class .
:ClassC a owl:Class .

:hasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:domain :ClassA, :ClassB;
    rdfs:range :ClassC .

:instanceA a :ClassA ;
    :hasClassC instanceC .
:instanceC a :ClassC .
```

Problem: reasoner output:

```
:instanceA a :ClassB .
```

Workaround with SHACL:

```
:ClassA a owl:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property  :ClassA-hasClassC .

:ClassA-hasClassC  rdf:type  sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path   :hasClassC ;
  sh:class  :ClassC .

:ClassB a owl:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property  :ClassB-hasClassC .

:ClassB-hasClassC  rdf:type  sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path   :hasClassC ;
  sh:class  :ClassC .
```

Comment: What is the outcome you desire? Please provide a minimal complete example illustrating the problem you are experiencing and the outcome you desire.

Comment: In addition to the answer: there are also scoped domain and range: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825404, but, AFAIK, the only tool that can visualuze them is SDont: https://github.com/cogan-shimizu/SDont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have solved this in SHACL is by having 2 different shapes: one for when `ClassA` is the domain and one for when `ClassB` is the domain.

To achieve something similar in OWL you will require 2 object properties: one for when `ClassA` is the domain and one for when `ClassB` is the domain.

```
:classAHasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :ClassA;
  rdfs:range :ClassC .

:classBHasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :ClassB;
  rdfs:range :ClassC .

:instanceA a :ClassA ;
  :classAHasClassC instanceC .
```

To make this even more clear, you may want to add a parent property and state that properties `classAHasClassC` and `classBHasClassC` are disjoint:

```
:hasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty

:classAHasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasClassC;
  rdfs:domain :ClassA;
  rdfs:range :ClassC .

:classBHasClassC a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasClassC;
  owl:propertyDisjointWith :classAHasClassC
  rdfs:domain :ClassB;
  rdfs:range :ClassC .
```

Lastly, a common mistake that is made is the thinking that if you have `ClassA, ClassB` as the domain of `hasClassC`, that it means the domain is the union of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Instead, what `ClassA, ClassB` means is that the domain is the **intersection** of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. To specify that the union should be used, one has to use the following:

```
rdfs:domain [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
  owl:unionOf (:ClassA
               :ClassB
              )
            ] ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, that´s the core problem. Defining multiple ranges or domain is by default ClassA AND ClassB, not OR. By assuming a closed world, what´s the best practise ? One would be adding class-specific properties (in owl or shacl). Another one is using unionOf, but that results in blanknodes.

Comment: The primary goal of OWL reasoners is to do consistency checking - that is it checks the relationship between classes. Though it does consider individuals, individuals are not the primary concern. OWL reasoners inherently make the open world assumption. SHACL is geared towards traditional data validation (closed world assumption). If your primary aim is data validation, then SHACL is your better option. If you want to find logical inconsistencies in how your classes relate to each other using OWL makes sense. You can read more  [here](https://spinrdf.org/shacl-and-owl.html).